# QGIS - Label polygon with different projections

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, polygon, labeling

I have a polygon layer projected in an UTM. In properties I checked 'show all labels for this layer'. Does anyone know why the label does not show until zoom 15:1 in QGIS with CRS-4326, while in another projection (an UTM) it will show always?

[image: Properties label]